# FBSDKShareDialog opening Facebook sometimes crashes

Tags: ios, facebook

I am having a issue with the FBSDKShareDialog. Sometimes, once Facebook opens, Facebook will crash. This is almost 90% re-producable when I kill the Facebook app and then process my FBSDKShareDialog code. Works fine after Facebook is open. Any thoughts?

Code for launching FBSDKShareDialog is like this:

```
FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [[FBSDKSharePhoto alloc] init];
photo.image = self.shareItem.fullImage;
photo.userGenerated = YES;
photo.caption = self.shareItem.fileDescription;

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *content = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
content.photos = @[photo];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];

});
```

Facebook crashes with:

Process:             Facebook [6415]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/FACCA335-ACE0-40BE-94B7-92BF08B0CDC3/Facebook.app/Facebook
Identifier:          com.facebook.Facebook
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1858a82d8 __exceptionPreprocess + 132
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1970cc0e4 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1858af3a4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 220

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using and what version of the FB app do you have? If you can consistently get a repro, I would suggest creating a sample app, and attaching it to a bug report here: developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I was on sdk 4.1, now updating to 4.4.0, seems fixed with either that or the newest Facebook iOS app.